# Programmatically build Junit recursive Suite with Junit4

Tags: java, junit, junit4

With annotation, it's easy to set up Junit 'recursive' Suite :

```
 @SuiteClasses({MyTest.class})
 public class MySuite{}
```

then

```
 @SuiteClasses({MySuite.class})
 public class MySweetSuite {}
```

Launching MySweetSuite will launch MySuite that will launch Test.

But how to do this programmatically, to launch the whole thing with JunitCore?
Right now, I can just create the MySuite with

```
Class<?>[] tests = { MyTest.class};
Suite mySuite = new Suite(myBuilder, tests);
```

How can I do the 'parent' mySweetSuite ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jUnit Documentation](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/junit/framework/TestSuite.html) the `TestSuite implements Test`.
Therefore try the following:

```
Class<?>[] testClasses = { MySweetSuite.class }
TestSuite suite = new TestSuite(testClasses);
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question, I'm trying to build a Suite object from another Suite object, not from from another class

Comment: @StéphanePiette And just calling [TestSuite#addTest](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/junit/framework/TestSuite.html#addTest(junit.framework.Test) is not working?

Comment: This only works for Junit3, where tests have to extends TestCase and method have to start with 'test'